# Apollo guidance computer ROM addressing using the ROM bank register, what is the bank register size?

Tags: apollo-program, guidance, computer

The Apollo guidance computer had 36 K words of core rope ROM. To address 36864 words, a 15 bit memory address for up to 32768 words is not enough, 16 bits are needed.

This Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikiyy.com/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer#Memory) describes the ROM addressing. The 10 lower bits of the address field of an instruction select the word within a 1024 words.

There is an Fbank register of 4 bit to select the ROM bank and 1 bit Sbank extension to address the last 4 kilowords.

But a bit is missing, 10+4+1 is 15 only and we need 16 bits. Therefore the Fbank register should be 5 bits, not 4.

Am I right about the size of the Fbank register?

Comment: possibly mentioned here? [Apollo Guidance Computer Restored, Used to Mine Bitcoin](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/294784-apollo-guidance-computer-restored-used-to-mine-bitcoin)

Answer (score 5):

That appears to be the description of the Block 1. The Block 2 is the one with 36 kilowords of memory. It additionally seems to be wrong about the number of bits in the Bank register.

https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Block1.html#CPU_Architecture_Registers has the Block 1 details, and states that the high 5 bits of the Bank register are used.

https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/assembly_language_manual.html#Memory_Map has Block 2 details: the FB register again has 5 bits of bank index, and the SB bit is the 16th bit needed to access the last 4 banks.

Comment: possibly mentioned here? [Apollo Guidance Computer Restored, Used to Mine Bitcoin](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/294784-apollo-guidance-computer-restored-used-to-mine-bitcoin)